# Spring MVC + AngularJS + JWT Token Expiration - HowTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jwt

I would like to ensure that my JSON Web tokens are revoked/expire after a configurable ammount of time and i have the following set up:

Security Filter:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import yourwebproject2.service.UserService;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author: kameshr
 */
public class JWTTokenAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static List<Pattern> AUTH_ROUTES = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<String> NO_AUTH_ROUTES = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String JWT_KEY = "JWT-TOKEN-SECRET";

    static {
        AUTH_ROUTES.add(Pattern.compile("/api/*"));
        NO_AUTH_ROUTES.add("/api/user/authenticate");
        NO_AUTH_ROUTES.add("/api/user/register");
    }

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTTokenAuthFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");
        String authenticationHeader = request.getHeader("authentication");
        String route = request.getRequestURI();

        // no auth route matching
        boolean needsAuthentication = false;

        for (Pattern p : AUTH_ROUTES) {
            if (p.matcher(route).matches()) {
                needsAuthentication = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(route.startsWith("/api/")) {
            needsAuthentication = true;
        }

        if (NO_AUTH_ROUTES.contains(route)) {
            needsAuthentication = false;
        }

        // Checking whether the current route needs to be authenticated
        if (needsAuthentication) {
            // Check for authorization header presence
            String authHeader = null;
            if (authorizationHeader == null || authorizationHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                if (authenticationHeader == null || authenticationHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    authHeader = null;
                } else {
                    authHeader = authenticationHeader;
                    LOG.info("authentication: " + authenticationHeader);
                }
            } else {
                authHeader = authorizationHeader;
                LOG.info("authorization: " + authorizationHeader);
            }

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(authHeader) || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new AuthCredentialsMissingException("Missing or invalid Authorization header.");
            }

            final String token = authHeader.substring(7); // The part after "Bearer "
            try {
                final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(JWT_KEY)
                        .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                request.setAttribute("claims", claims);

                // Now since the authentication process if finished
                // move the request forward
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new AuthenticationFailedException("Invalid token. Cause:"+e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Method that creates the Authentication token:

```
String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getEmail())
                .claim("role", user.getRole().name()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, JWTTokenAuthFilter.JWT_KEY).compact();
        authResp.put("token", token);
        authResp.put("user", user);
```

Above i have all the claims that i am using on the JWT , i would like to request that the token is revoked after x ammount of time(of inactivity if possible).

How could i achieve this using JWT / Spring MVC / Angular JS / Spring Security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set expiration for token

```
 String token = Jwts.builder()
     .setSubject(user.getEmail())
     .claim("role", user.getRole().name())
     .setIssuedAt(new Date())
     .setExpiration(expirationDate) 
     .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, WTTokenAuthFilter.JWT_KEY)
     .compact();
```

Then, `parseClaimsJws` will raise `ExpiredJwtException` if currentTime>expirationDate

To revoke a valid token is a hard technique with no easy solutions:

1) Maintain a blacklist in server and compare for each request

2) Set a small expiration time and issue new token

3) Insert the login time in the token and compare if acomplish your criteria

4) remove the jwt in client side

Ser [Invalidating client side JWT session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507714/invalidating-client-side-jwt-session/37520125#37520125)