# What to store in a JWT?

Tags: session, cookies, jwt

How do you guys deal with the same user on multiple devices? Won't data such as `{admin: true}` become stale except for the device that changed it?

Should this even be in a JWT? If not, and we resort to only putting the user ID, won't that be just like a cookie-based session since we store the state on the server?

Comment: Listing some useful properties I thought were useful so far: `userID`, `lastActive`.

`scopes` would be useful if you have a blacklisting feature that'll revoke all of the user's keys

Answer (score 41):

The JWT [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-8) establishes three classes of claims:

- **Registered claims** like `sub`, `iss`, `exp` or `nbf`
- **Public claims** with public names or names [registered by IANA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1) which contain values that should be unique like `email`, `address` or `phone_number`. See [full list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml)
- **Private claims** to use in your own context and values can collision

None of these claims are mandatory

A JWT is self-contained and should avoid use the server session providing the necessary data to perform the authentication (no need of server storage and database access). Therefore, `role` info can be included in JWT.

When using several devices there are several reasons to **revoke tokens before expiration**, for example when user changes password, permissions or account deleted by admin. In this case you would need a blacklist or an alternative mechanism to reject the tokens

A blacklist can include the token unique ID `jti` or simply set an entry (`sub` - `iss`) after updating critical data on user (password, persmissions, etc) and `currentTime - maxExpiryTime < last iss`. The entry can be discarded when `currentTime - maxExpiryTime > last_modified` (no more non-expired tokens sent).

---

### Registered Claims

The following Claim Names are registered in the IANA "JSON Web Token Claims" registry established by [Section 10.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1)

- `iss` (issuer): identifies the principal that issued the JWT.
- `sub` (subject): identifies the principal that is the subject of the JWT. Must be unique
- `aud` (audience): identifies the recipients that the JWT is intended for (array of strings/uri)
- `exp` (expiration time): identifies the expiration time (UTC Unix) after which you must no longer accept this token. It should be after the issued-at time.
- `nbf`(not before): identifies the UTC Unix time before which the JWT must not be accepted
- `iat` (issued at): identifies the UTC Unix time at which the JWT was issued
- `jti` (JWT ID): provides a unique identifier for the JWT.

### Example

```
{
    "iss": "stackoverflow",
    "sub": "joe",
    "aud": ["all"],
    "iat": 1300819370,
    "exp": 1300819380,
    "jti": "3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301"
    "context": {
        "user": {
            "key": "joe",
            "displayName": "Joe Smith"
        },
        "roles":["admin","finaluser"]
    }
}
```

See alternatives here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37520125/6371459

Comment: I'm trying to expand on #2: What to put in public claims. I don't think `email` and `address` are good examples because they *should* be configurable and without blacklisting the token, so the user doesn't have to login again from another device. However, properties such as `admin` or `scopes` would be good candidates for your blacklisting approach. I'm simply looking for other properties I could add to the token.

Comment: Additionally, you have to keep in mind that it should be as short as possible because it is mainly used in a web context.

Comment: Check this link to get the actual registry of claims http://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml. To build a blacklist you would need to use a unique ID for token in `jti`, or include an userID in `sub`. Using also `iss` you can control how to revoke only old tokens

Comment: Is't it bad practice to store phone and email in JWT token? A security problem?