# Do I add Added Claims from AspNetUserClaims to JwtSecurityToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using Asp.net Identity Core and made some claims in "AspNetUserClaims". Now I am wondering if I should add all these claims to the JwtSecurityToken when a user logs in?

Or should I be grabbing them another way?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we store identifier claims like userid/username , role info like guest/admin in JWT tokens . You can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906429/5751404) for more details about claims in JWT token.

You can add user's claims which are small , important to your client to JWT token . If doing that , be careful with the size and better not include sensitive information.

But I would recommend not to keep the user profile info into claims . You can use the token to make Api call on server to get the user's profile information by looking up the database .

Comment: yea I understand storing their role in the jwt token but what about individual claims of that role like "can_read" or something like that. Or is it better to just query that stuff later?

Comment: @chobo2 This is role info, you can add that in JWT token .