# ASP.net Core 2.0 JWT Token Refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I've implemented the JWT Bearer Auth along with the Identity Cookie Auth, one for UI and the other for REST APIs in my .NET Core 2.0 project.

Everything works as of now with the JWT token where I've set the expiry time as 30 mins, the same as the Identity Cookie expiry time.

I've not come across any official docs for the implementation of the refresh tokens for JWT. There are 1 or 2 blog posts though on this topic but they are too complex and high maintenance.

So, wanted to know if the concept of refresh tokens applies here or do we only use the JWT access token ?

On researching, this is the closest I came to an answer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330013/jwt-token-refresh-sliding-sessions-and-signout)

Comment: were you able to find a good article/ solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) which is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core 2 and implements refresh token protocol