# Refresh token expired as soon as access token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I am implementing JWT refresh token, and setting different time expire for refresh token, but it is taking expire time same as access token

```
var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
DateTime refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<DateTime>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime");
```

**To save in database**

```
RefreshToken refreshToken = new RefreshToken();
refreshToken.Token = refreshTokenId;
refreshToken.PrivateKey = context.SerializeTicket();
refreshToken.ExpiryDate = refreshTokenLifeTime;
```

**End saving Db**

```
context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now;
context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshTokenLifeTime;

context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
```

Any help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where in provided code you set different expiration times? I see two expirations time set to the same value in this code.

Comment: This is for refresh token

Comment: Please add the logic for your access token. If the times are the same, we need to see both tokens.

Comment: Can you write your whole implementation code for IAuthenticationTokenProvider in your question?

Comment: Ur seems be using same `refreshTokenLifeTime` both tokens.

Answer (score 4):

**The refresh token does not extend the time of expiration, this is called sliding expiration and you cannot do it with access tokens. I have used the refresh token to update user Roles, not the expiration time.**
Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330013/jwt-token-refresh-sliding-sessions-and-signout) for Slidingexpiration
I used the below code to refresh token and persisting it

```
  public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{

    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
        {
            return;
        }

        var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime"); 

            var token = new RefreshToken() 
            { 
                Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                ClientId = clientid, 
                Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime)) 
            };

            context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

            token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

            var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

            if (result)
            {
                context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {

        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

            if (refreshToken != null )
            {
                //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the request context contains all the claims stored previously for this user, and you need to add the logic which allows you to issue new claims or update the existing claims and contain them into the new access token generated before 
you need the add the below code in the AuthorizationServerProvider Class you have.

```
public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        var currentClient = context.ClientId;

        if (originalClient != currentClient)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
        newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

        var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(newTicket);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with my code, the same code, I have pasted only refresh token logic

Comment: The same logic implemented so each time you generate access token refresh token will also be generated, so where you are using longer validity of refresh token

Comment: please check the answer again, I have updated it to be more convenient

Comment: This is same I have implemented. Have you checked that your refresh token stay longer than access token, per your code and mine code also, when access token suppose to expire we use refresh token to regenerate access token, at that point refresh token also get refreshed and generate new refresh token

Comment: Oh, I think you got it wrong, the refresh token is not to extend the time of expiration, this is called sliding expiration and you cannot do it with access tokens. I have used the refresh token to update user Roles, not the expiration time.

Comment: check this link might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330013/jwt-token-refresh-sliding-sessions-and-signout

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
DateTime refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<DateTime>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime");
```

you are reading the lifetime, not setting it to any new value.

Comment: context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshTokenLifeTime;... HERE I am setting value

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, which you just have read from the Owin context. You are not generating av tokenvalue anywhere (in the code sample you have supplied).