# User Authentication with REST in a web app secured with Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, spring-security

My Spring Boot-based web app authenticates against a remote REST api. To do so, I have extended `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` like so:

```
public class RestAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        Credentials creds = new Credentials();
        creds.setUsername(username);
        creds.setPassword(password);

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            ResponseEntity<Authentication> auth = template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate",
                    creds, Authentication.class);
            if (auth.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

                String token = auth.getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0); // Great! Now what?

                return new User(authentication.getName(), password,
                        Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
            }

            throw new BadCredentialsException("Failed to authenticate, server returned " + auth.getStatusCodeValue());

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) { // Check for type of error
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getStatusText());
        }
    }
}
```

This works great. However my problem is that subsequent access to the API will require the API key being provided in the `RestTemplate` headers. This is the 
line :

```
String token = auth.getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0); // Great! Now what?
```

What I'm after is some way to persist that token at the session level for future access. Down the line, I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication userDetails = context.getAuthentication() ;
```

where somehow `userDetails` would contain the API key.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is **you** designing & implementing your own security solution. The framework provides you a way to implement how you resolve `UserDetails` based on **credentials**.

I see the question for *subsequent* invocations of this. For that reason "old school" web apps have sessions, but "new school" thinks it's "not cool" anymore as it "does not scale" ( or whatever other reasons ) and I assume you're one of those.

If you don't want to use sessions - then you need to get your user from the database ( or cache, or session store, or what you like ) based on some identified.

Your **current** implementation provides this feature by using *username* and *password*, but I assume you don't want to keep that in memory & send with every request.

So you want to generate a token, store it in the database ( or cache, or token store, or session store ) and then implement another `AuthenticationProvider` which will next time read the `UserDetails` based on token, not user credentials.

You could use a `JWT` token which actually is able to serialize your whole `UserDetails` object into the token itself & send it over the wire, but I wouldn't recommend that either as there is no way to invalidate it, unless you're storing the token `id` in your database / session store.

More to read here: [Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a simple matter of extending `WebAuthenticationDetails`, like so:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6951476359238150556L;
    private String token ;

    public JwtAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JwtAuthenticationDetails [token=" + token + "; " + super.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

And then to register that in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, JwtAuthenticationDetails> getAuthenticationDetailsSource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, JwtAuthenticationDetails>() {

        @Override
        public JwtAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
            return new JwtAuthenticationDetails(context);

        }

    } ;
}
```

Finally,

in my `RestAuthenticationProvider`, I can store the token in the authentication details:

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    String token = getToken(authentication.getName(), password);

    JwtAuthenticationDetails details = (JwtAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails() ;
    details.setToken(token);
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(token);
    return new User(authentication.getName(), password, authorities);
}
```