# How to revoke JWT Bearer Token in Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, jwt

1. Can we make jwt bearer token as invalid

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question should contain a single question.

Comment: please read on how to ask a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)

Comment: you'll find a comprehensive answer in the linked Q/A

Answer (score 0):

A JWT bearer token is supposed to be a self-contained token that includes a verifiable expiry timestamp. Typical deployments won't allow to revoke it since there's no entity that will tell you that it is revoked. If you control the "issuer" side you can change that behavior yourself but it defeats the primary reason for using JWTs.

Comment: what primary reason?

Comment: That it is self-contained.