# How to logout the authenticated token correctly after API call returns response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, fetch

I have the below code on client side, on click event It sends a request server side node to get a token, then when token is returned from external url response. It passes that token onto the second ajax call to call a specific api route.

This all works great, but I want to logout the token after I get the response from a specific api route (using the token). So that after the response I don't have the token staying alive.

What would be a good way to accomplish this? My current solution is when the response for the specific api route is given, send a fetch request to /tokenrequest/logout to logout the token. But not sure if that is a correct or good way to do it.

```js
getdata.addEventListener("click", function(e) { //simple button click to initiate api
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/jdeapi",
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    let rawData = JSON.parse(data);
    var token = rawData.userInfo.token;
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/sendtojde",
      data: {
        token
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
  })
})
```

The node server side code is as follows for the token request

```js
router.get('/jdeapi', function(req, res) {
  let url = 'https://Aisserver:port/jderest/tokenrequest';
  let data = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    deviceName: 'riolivApp'
  }
  fetch(url, {
      credential: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => res.json(text));
})
```

Then after the 2nd ajax call on client side, the server side call to fetch a specific api is as follows

```js
router.post('/sendtojde', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.token);
  let url = "https://Aisserver:port/jderest/poservice"
  let data = {
    token: req.body.token,
    deviceName: 'riolivApp',
    applicationName: "P4310",
    version: "RMI0001"
  }

  fetch(url, {
      credential: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => response.text())
    .then(text =>
      res.json(text));
})
```

Comment: You could clear the token on the client side, and then set some expiration time for the token such as one day

Comment: @tenza but I want to logout the token as soon as response is sent back so it doesn't stay around. Can I do that instead?

Comment: You could, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens