# How to logout user when he changes password from all browsers (Django-rest-auth, JWT)?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

First of all, i am new with `django-rest-framework` so please excuse me if I'm wrong.

I'm working with `django-rest-auth` and `django-restframework-jwt` to authenticate users. I'm saving the `jwt` token in localStorage everytime the user logs in.

The problem That I'm facing now is that when I log in with same credentials in two browsers and then I change password in one of them, the other account still valid and user still can navigate and see all pages even though the  password has changed.

I wanted to make his `JWT` token invalid when he changes password so that he will be automatically logged out. But I couldn't find a way to expire his token in [official documentation of `Django REST framework JWT`](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

I tried to track the moment of changing password by generating manually a new JWT token for user, but this is not working (maybe because the existing token is still valid)

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def revoke_tokens(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    existing_user = User.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)

    if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
        if instance.password != existing_user.password:
            # If user has changed his password, generate manually a new token for him
            jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
            jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(instance)
            payload['orig_iat'] = timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())
            instance.token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

After reading some documenations and posts, it seems that this is not quite easy with only `jwt` since it's stateless, But could somebody point me the direction where to go?

Should I remove `JWT` authentication?

Is there a work around that can help me on this ?

Thanks a lot.

---

**EDIT:**

I found a comment in [a similar post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23089839/5165188) by @Travis stating that

> A common approach for invalidating tokens when a user changes their
>   password is to sign the token with a hash of their password. Thus if
>   the password changes, any previous tokens automatically fail to
>   verify. You can extend this to logout by including a last-logout-time
>   in the user's record and using a combination of the last-logout-time
>   and password hash to sign the token. This requires a DB lookup each
>   time you need to verify the token signature, but presumably you're
>   looking up the user anyway

I'm trying to implement that ..I will update my post if it worked.
Otherwise, I still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of work, I ended up by overriding the `JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` and  adding the last digits of the user's hash of password in the payload of `JWT` token (since adding all the hash of password in the payload is not a good practice) 
and then creating a `custom middleware` that intercepts all requests.

in every request I  check from `jwt token` if the hash of the password matches the existing user's hash (if not that means that the user has  changed his password)

if they are different then I raise an error and logout the user  with old hash of password.

in config file :

```
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'your.path.jwt.jwt_payload_handler',
```

and in the root stated in the config file :

```
 def jwt_payload_handler(user):
      username_field = get_username_field()
      username = get_username(user)

      payload = {
    'user_id': user.pk,
    'username': username,
    'pwd': user.password[-10:],
    'exp': datetime.utcnow() + api_settings.JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA
    }
if hasattr(user, 'email'):
    payload['email'] = user.email
if isinstance(user.pk, uuid.UUID):
    payload['user_id'] = str(user.pk)

      payload[username_field] = username
      return payload
```

and then this is the custom middleware :

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from rest_framework_jwt.utils import jwt_decode_handler
from config.settings.base import JWT_AUTH
from trp.users.models import User
class JWTAuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
   def process_request(self, request):
      jwt_user_pwd = self.get_jwt_user_pwd(request)
      # check if last digits of password read from jwt token matches the hash of the current user in DB
      if jwt_user_pwd is not None:
        if jwt_user_pwd['pwd'] != jwt_user_pwd['user'].password[-10:]:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

@staticmethod
def get_jwt_user_pwd(request):
    token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
    # Remove the prefix from token name so that decoding the token gives us correct credentials
    token = str(token).replace(JWT_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX'] + ' ', '')
    if token:
        try:
            payload = jwt_decode_handler(token)
            authenticated_user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
        except Exception as e:
            authenticated_user = None
            payload = {}
        if authenticated_user and payload:
            return {'user': authenticated_user, 'pwd': payload.get('pwd')}
    return None
```

To logout the user I have read the status code of the request 'in this case  403' from front end : (I'm using `Angular` in my case) and then logout the user 
I hope it helps someone in the future .

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It is all about token expiry time - If you keep this short (like 10-15 minutes) - you can no bother with invalidating it when a password or some permissions will change. Token will be invalidated always after some short period of time and a new one will be issued.

If you are using JWT as long living token (which is not good practice) - you will have problems.

Because actions like changing a password and invalidating other tokens (different session) (or force recreate) needs to be stored somewhere else (like some NoSQL store) - and checked for each session that some special action is required - and then you are losing the stateless advantage of JWT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what should I use instead? 
should I remove authenticating with `JWT` ? in my case I have front and backend seperated : front with `angular` and back with `python/django` 
Thanks

Comment: Well, implement renew short token cycle on the frontend and backend :) 
Otherwise - allow your session to store some state - or store the JWT tokens somewhere and blacklist them when password change occurs.