# How to implement Logout feature using jwt tokens in spring boot backend(using rest end points) Implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

Iam new to spring security and i was going through spring boot jwt and the process but i dont know how to use logout feature through jwt .
For example when a user click logout at after that time using that token we can not access the secured Rest end points.

Now i want is implementation of logout functionality using JWT(Spring Boot Rest Api)that is used in real time projects and the code for it.

```
Please if any one can provide me the github link to the solution
```

**or can send me the code at**

```
ag.rajat113@gmail.com
```

and anything related to latest spring security projects real time (Backend)
and also of oAuth2 material please send me i need this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On logout, you can perform the following actions

*Remove the token from the client*

You can remove the token from Client (Local storage, Session/Cookie). Note that it will not prevent the client access as you removing from only client side and for server, it is still valid Token

*Maintain Token blacklist*

When a client performs logout action. Add that token to blacklist and for next request check token is in a blacklist. If yes then prevent the access. As you have to check for every request it will be costly for large applications

*Short expiry time*

If you keep the token expiry times at short enough intervals and have the running client keep track and request updates when necessary, It will be working as a complete logout system. The problem with this method is that it makes it impossible to keep the user logged in between closes of the client code (depending on how long you make the expiry interval).

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens) for Details

Comment: thanks Patel Romil for the solution but if you can provide the code than it would be useful to me as Iam new in this but thanks for giving me the concept

Comment: Hello @RajatAgrawal, you can start it, if some issue occurs I will be happy in trying to solve it

Comment: please give me your mail id i will send you the code and thanks again

Comment: Thanks @PatelRomil now I got the concept and thanks for helping me

Comment: Welcome @RajatAgrawal, I am glad that it was helpful