# force expire jwt token in adonis js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, jwt

Is there a way to force expire `jwt token` **(not refresh token)** in `adonis-js`. 
I am creating a token on login and setting its time to expire for 10 mins. When I log out I want to force expire that token before 10 mins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
async login({ request, auth }) {
  const { email, password } = request.all();
  const user = await auth.validate(email, password, true);
  const { name, admin, confirmed } = user;
```

> ```
>   const token = await auth.generate(user, false, { expiresIn: '10m' })
> ```

```
  return { token, user }
}
```