# Delete The Token of User , After Deleted it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have Web API controllers. When I delete any user, the token of it should be deleted from azureadb2c. How can I do that in asp.net?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invalidate Jwt token received from azure ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624916/how-to-invalidate-jwt-token-received-from-azure-ad)

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [invalidate the tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) if the user is soft deleted but it wont work when the user is hard deleted. 
Once the token is issued by Azure AD it can't be deleted. What you can do is you can validate the token with the requests