# Can I force a logout or expiration of a JWT token?

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

For authentication currently we are using JWT, so once a token is created it's created for a lifetime, and if we set a time expire, the token will expire.

Is there any way to expire token?

While clicking log out button, I need to destroy the token.

I'm using ASP.NET Core WebAPI.

Comment: Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think cancelling JWT is the best way to handle logout. Piotr explained well in his blog: [Cancel JWT tokens](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2018/04/25/canceling-jwt-tokens-in-net-core/)

> We will start with the interface:
>
> ```
> public interface ITokenManager
> {
>     Task<bool> IsCurrentActiveToken();
>     Task DeactivateCurrentAsync();
>     Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(string token);
>     Task DeactivateAsync(string token);
> }
> ```
>
> And process with its implementation, where the basic idea is to keep
> track of deactivated tokens only and remove them from a cache when not
> needed anymore (meaning when the expiry time passed) – they will be no
> longer valid anyway.
>
> ```
> public class TokenManager : ITokenManager
> {
>     private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
>     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
>     private readonly IOptions<JwtOptions> _jwtOptions;
>  
>     public TokenManager(IDistributedCache cache,
>             IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
>             IOptions<JwtOptions> jwtOptions
>         )
>     {
>         _cache = cache;
>         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
>         _jwtOptions = jwtOptions;
>     }
>  
>     public async Task<bool> IsCurrentActiveToken()
>         => await IsActiveAsync(GetCurrentAsync());
>  
>     public async Task DeactivateCurrentAsync()
>         => await DeactivateAsync(GetCurrentAsync());
>  
>     public async Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(string token)
>         => await _cache.GetStringAsync(GetKey(token)) == null;
>  
>     public async Task DeactivateAsync(string token)
>         => await _cache.SetStringAsync(GetKey(token),
>             " ", new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
>             {
>                 AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow =
>                     TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_jwtOptions.Value.ExpiryMinutes)
>             });
>  
>     private string GetCurrentAsync()
>     {
>         var authorizationHeader = _httpContextAccessor
>             .HttpContext.Request.Headers["authorization"];
>  
>         return authorizationHeader == StringValues.Empty
>             ? string.Empty
>             : authorizationHeader.Single().Split(" ").Last();
>     }
>     
>     private static string GetKey(string token)
>         => $"tokens:{token}:deactivated";
> }
> ```
>
> As you can see, there are 2 helper methods that will use the current
> HttpContext in order to make things even easier.
>
> Next, let’s create a middleware that will check if the token was
> deactivated or not. That’s the reason why we should keep them in cache
> – hitting the database with every request instead would probably kill
> your app sooner or later (or at least make it really, really slow):
>
> ```
> public class TokenManagerMiddleware : IMiddleware
> {
>     private readonly ITokenManager _tokenManager;
>  
>     public TokenManagerMiddleware(ITokenManager tokenManager)
>     {
>         _tokenManager = tokenManager;
>     }
>     
>     public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
>     {
>         if (await _tokenManager.IsCurrentActiveToken())
>         {
>             await next(context);
>             
>             return;
>         }
>         context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Eventually, let’s finish our journey with implementing an endpoint for
> canceling the tokens:
>
> ```
> [HttpPost("tokens/cancel")]
> public async Task<IActionResult> CancelAccessToken()
> {
>     await _tokenManager.DeactivateCurrentAsync();
>  
>     return NoContent();
> }
> ```
>
> For sure, we could make it more sophisticated, via passing the token
> via URL, or by canceling all of the existing user tokens at once
> (which would require an additional implementation to keep track of
> them), yet this is a basic sample that just works.
>
> Make sure that you will register the required dependencies in your
> container and configure the middleware:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     ...
>     services.AddTransient<TokenManagerMiddleware>();
>     services.AddTransient<ITokenManager, Services.TokenManager>();
>     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
>     services.AddDistributedRedisCache(r => { r.Configuration = Configuration["redis:connectionString"]; 
>     ...
> }
>  
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
>     ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
> {
>     ...
>     app.UseAuthentication();
>     app.UseMiddleware<TokenManagerMiddleware>();
>     app.UseMvc();
> }
> ```
>
> And provide a configuration for Redis in appsettings.json file:
>
> ```
> "redis": {
>   "connectionString": "localhost"
> }
> ```
>
> Try to run the application now and invoke the token cancellation[sic]
> endpoint – that’s it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the best way to logout is just remove token from the client. And you can make lifetime of tokens short (5-15 minutes) and implement refresh tokens for additions security. In this case there are less chance for attacker to do something with your JWT

Comment: Yes @Mateech, Tried this too but we are failing in Grey box testing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have implemented the login scenario with the refresh token, You can remove the refresh token from the server and then , and then you should remove the token from the client.