# Laravel / vuejs JWT token

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am having a problem.

I am implementing a user management function. The administrator will manage the customer's account.

In this case, a client is using the system, and the administrator blocks that client.

How to remove the guest JWT token to redirect their screen to a screen log in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can invalidate the token first then use route middleware for protecting routes. Take a look at this link, maybe it can be an inspiration for you to invalidate tokens.
[Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).