# Log out using JWT

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt, express-jwt

I'm currently working on an authentication system Mongoose (i'm new to it), and I would like some feedback on my approach to handling JWT token expiration in the context of user logout.

I have implemented a strategy to check the validity of JWT tokens by comparing the `loggedoutAt` attribute in my user schema with the `iat` (issued at) claim of the decoded JWT token. If the `loggedoutAt` timestamp is present and greater than the `iat`, I consider the token invalid and return a 401 status.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
export const auth = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1-) Check if token exists
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  )
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) return next(new ApiError("Please login or sign up", 401));

  // 2-) Check if token is not valid or if token is expired
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

  // 3-) Check if user exists
  const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.userId);
  if (!user)
    return next(new ApiError("Token invalid: User dose not exists", 401));

  // 4-) Check if the user has been loggedout with this token
  if (user.loggedoutAt) {
    const loggedoutAtTimestamp = parseInt(
      user.loggedoutAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );

    if (loggedoutAtTimestamp > decodedToken.iat)
      return next(new ApiError("Token invalid: User logged out", 401));
  }

  req.user = user;
  next();
});
```

And here is the log out function:

```
export const logout = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.user.loggedoutAt = Date.now();
  await req.user.save();
  res.status(200).json({ status: "logged out" });
});
```

My Questions:

Is this strategy a reasonable approach for handling token invalidation upon user logout, or are there better practices I should consider?
Are there potential pitfalls or improvements I should be aware of in this implementation?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your implementation, if a user is logged in from multiple devices, logging out from one device automatically logs the user out from other devices.

Take a look at this question and the answer on how to invalidate JWT
[Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)