# AAD Logout Azure Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a web app in azure with authorization/authentication being set-up.
Once you logged in the web app you would be able to get the token using:

> https:{webappname}.azurewebsites.com/.auth/me

then i tried to get the token and used it in postman using AUTHORIZATION header and it worked i was able to access the site with postman using that token. Now my concerns in after i logged out using:

> https:{webappname}.azurewebsites.com/.auth/logout

I can still access the site using the token that i got recently. can someone explain why is this happening.

Thanks :D

Comment: That's happening because logout isn't necessarily invalidating the token. You could try to maintain a custom list on server for such invalid tokens. There are other SO posts with similar discussion so I'm not adding a new answer here. Take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744454/azure-mobile-service-active-directory-authentication-x-zumo-auth-token-valid-in?lq=1 and here's another popular one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens

Comment: @RohitSaigal Thanks.

Comment: @bkastral you're welcome. Initially I thought I'm definitely going to find a duplicate for this one, but I guess I was wrong.. on searching a few times I couldn't really find anything with similar title :) I'm adding the comment as an answer for any future references.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because logout isn't necessarily invalidating the token.

In order to do something at your end, you could try to maintain a custom list on server for such invalid tokens.

Please look at these two SO posts discussing in a lot more detail.

- [azure mobile service active directory authentication X-ZUMO-AUTH
  token valid in postman after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744454/azure-mobile-service-active-directory-authentication-x-zumo-auth-token-valid-in?lq=1)
- [Invalidating JSON Web Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens)